# How to remove Item from an array with react and firebase

Tags: javascript

When I add an item to the array it works but the splice does not.

```
const handleSportsFollowed = async (sport) => {
  if (selectedSports.includes(sport)) {
    selectedSports.splice(sport, 1);
    alert("Removed");
  } else {
    selectedSports.push(sport);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the `splice` method. You can have a look here [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: Is selectedSports a state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove elements that are equal to `sport` from the array using:

```
selectedSports = selectedSports.filter(x => x != sport)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = ['sport', 'sport1', 'sport2', 'sport3', 'sport3'];
const b = a.filter(x => x != 'sport');
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the index for splice. Check [Document](https://if%20(selectedSports.includes(sport))%20%7B%20%20%20selectedSports.splice(selectedSports.indexOf(sport),%201);%20%20%20console.log(%22if%20selectedSports%20%22,%20selectedSports);%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20%20%20selectedSports.push(sport);%20%20%20console.log(%22else%20selectedSports%22,%20selectedSports);%20%7D) how splice work

```
const handleSportsFollowed = async (sport) => {
 if (selectedSports.includes(sport)) {
   selectedSports.splice(selectedSports.indexOf(sport), 1);
    console.log("if selectedSports ", selectedSports);
  } else {
     selectedSports.push(sport);
    console.log("else selectedSports", selectedSports);
  }
```

Working example

```js
const selectedSports = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];

const testFun = (sport) => {
if (selectedSports.includes(sport)) {
  selectedSports.splice(selectedSports.indexOf(sport), 1);
  console.log("selectedSports ", selectedSports);
} else {
  selectedSports.push(sport);
  console.log("selectedSports", selectedSports);
}
}

testFun("March");
```